# Can't convince VBA about number formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get the following to agree on types:

```
Dim IMSPosition As Double
 IMSPosition = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(UniqueID, IMSData.Range("A:P"), 14, 0), 0)

If Abs(HubPosition * Multiplier + IMSPosition) < 1 Then
```

The goal is to see if the IMS position and the Hub Position have equal and opposite amounts, then flip them to be going in the same direction.

Without the Dim IMS, without the format, I get a type mismatch on the comparison line. With either or both the DIM and format, I get an overflow error on the IMS position line. I've tried various formats, I've tried changing the source data to be a number, I've done some googling, and I'm completely stuck.

Edit: Breaking and stepping through the code, the first 7 lines post fine, THEN it gets made. I looking into the number in question it gets mad about, and... nothing special. Another...

Wait, it's giant. Larger than a Long number. I think I found my issue...

Edit 2: Works OK, except when the Vlookup fails to find anything. Need to figure out how to tell it to behave like it was behaving before (when it was a string)

Edit 3: Trying to wrap the Vlookup in an iferror isn't going as swimmingly as I hoped

Edit 4: I managed to get it to work with the following code:

```
 IsinHUB = Not IsError(Application.Match(UniqueID, HubData.Range("C:C"), 0))
    isInIMS = Not IsError(Application.Match(UniqueID, IMSData.Range("A:A"), 0))
   If IsinHUB And isInIMS Then
 ' Compare here
End if
```

Comment: Where are "HubPosition" and "Multiplier" defined?

Comment: HubPosition and multiplier aren't defined - legacy sheets are fun. They are working properly as numbers, so I left that part out.

Comment: The **Format()** function returns a *String*.

Comment: The fully-qualified name for `Format` is `VBA.Strings.Format`. It's a string-formatting function that returns a `String`.

Comment: Got it- Format is wrong. Managed to figure out that my numbers were too large, change my dim, that worked, now I'm struggling to work out out to deal with a vlookup that doesn't find the ID - Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError isn't working as I hoped